# validateName function not working

Tags: javascript, html, regex, function, validation

In the following code the validateName function is not working at all.  Even when the correct characters are entered in the name text box the alert is still showing up.  What am I doing wrong?  It seems to only break because of the validateName function.  Once removed the other 2 work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <script>

/*
Check required form elements script-
By JavaScript Kit (http://javascriptkit.com)
Over 200+ free scripts here!
*/



function checkrequired(which){
var pass=true
if (document.images){
    for (i=0;i<which.length;i++){
        var tempobj=which.elements[i]
        if (tempobj.name.substring(0,8)=="required"){
            if (((tempobj.type=="text"||tempobj.type=="textarea")&&tempobj.value=='')||(tempobj.type.toString().charAt(0)=="s"&&tempobj.selectedIndex==-1)){
                pass=false
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
if (!pass){
    alert("One or more of the required elements are not completed. Please complete them, then submit again!")
    return false
}
else
    return true
}
</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

/**--------------------------
//* Validate Date Field script- By JavaScriptKit.com
//* For this script and 100s more, visit http://www.javascriptkit.com
//* This notice must stay intact for usage
---------------------------**/

function checkdate(input){
var validformat=/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ //Basic check for format validity
var returnval=false
if (!validformat.test(input.value))
    alert("Invalid Date Format. Please correct and submit again.")
else{ //Detailed check for valid date ranges
    var monthfield=input.value.split("/")[0]
    var dayfield=input.value.split("/")[1]
    var yearfield=input.value.split("/")[2]
    var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield-1, dayfield)
    if ((dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)||(dayobj.getDate()!=dayfield)||(dayobj.getFullYear()!=yearfield))
        alert("Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again.")
    else
        returnval=true
}
if (returnval==false) input.select()
return returnval
}

</script>
<script>
function validateName(name) { 
    var cap = /^[A-Z]{1}.+$/;
    var con = /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i;
    var vow = /[aeiou]/i;
    if(cap.test(name) && con.test(name) && vow.test(name)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Must be non-blank, must begin with a capital letter, and must contain at least one vowel and one consonant");
        return false;
    }
} 
</script>
            <title>Comments</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
    <body>
<form name="usercomments" onSubmit= "return checkrequired(this) || validateName(this.name) || checkdate(this.requiredbday)">
Please input a valid email address:<br />
<input type="text" size=18 name="requiredemail">
<br/>
<br/>
Full name:
<input type="text" size=30 name="name">
<br/>
<br/>
Please provide feedback:
<input type="text" size="80" style="height:200px" name="requiredmessage">
<br/>
<br/>
Phone number:
<input type="text" size=15 name="requiredphone">
<br/>
<br/>
Birth date (mm/dd/yyyy):
<input type="text" size=15 name="requiredbday">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it giving any error?

Answer (score 0):

In the validateName function you should check `name.value` just like in checkdate function.

Comment: <script>
function validateName(name) { 
    var cap = /^[A-Z]{1}.+$/;
    var con = /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i;
    var vow = /[aeiou]/i;
    if(cap.test(name.value) && con.test(name.value) && vow.test(name.value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Must be non-blank, must begin with a capital letter, and must contain at least one vowel and one consonant");
  return false;
    }
} 
</script>

Answer (score 0):

As Rafal was mentioning you should use the Value of the Name not only it's "ID"

For explanation or future test of your own. For script like this you can use the "ALERT" to see what you are looking for if it really is what you are testing or if it's really the "Value" you are expecting.

In this case try

```
alert(name)
```

then you can look if it returns what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line with `<form>` on:

```
<form name="usercomments" onSubmit="return checkrequired(this) && validateName(this.name) && checkdate(this.requiredbday)">
```